# spring cloud sidecar for rails app in heroku

Tags: heroku, microservices, netflix

Does it make sense to take advantage of netflix oss components(zuul, eureka, etc) from rails api microservices deployed in heroku?
What is the right way to deploy both a rails app and a spring cloud sidecar in heroku. same dyno? single web process? Also, what is the recommended approach for a centralized/dynamic configuration in heroku. spring cloud config, archaius, etcd?